# I've got a Jquery UI problem with pugx integration in symfony

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

I think it's a jquery UI problem's loading. I'm implementing [Pugx](https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXAutoCompleterBundle/blob/master/docs/index.md) and when I lauch yarn dev, I've got this error :

> autocompleter-jqueryui.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: $fakeInput.autocomplete is not a function

In my app.js :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-ui';
import '@pugx/autocompleter-bundle/js/autocompleter-jqueryui';
```

In webpack.config.js I added '.autoProvidejQuery()'.

This is my js.file :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
$('#postal_code_zipcode').autocompleter({
url_list: '/author_search',
url_get: '/author_get/'
})
```

I don't know why this error is displayed, any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Instead of importing 'jqueryui/ui/widgets/autocomplete';' I imported only jquery-ui